# ExtJS Google Map SetCenter ERROR

Tags: google-maps, extjs

```
    var layout = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                //renderTo: 'layout',
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight,
                //title: 'Border Layout', //no title will be blank
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{
                    title: 'Message List',
                    region: 'south',     // position for region
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height: 100,
                    split: true,         // enable resizing
                    collapsible: true,
                    margins: '0 5 5 5',
                    collapsed: true
                },tree,{
                    xtype: 'gmappanel',
                    region: 'center',
                    id : 'mygooglemap',
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.951941, 102.052002),
                    mapOptions: {
                        zoom: 7,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP                    
                    }
                    }],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody() //get the body and display Layout at there
            });
        });

function addInfoWindow(lat,lng) {
    var map123 = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap'); 
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map123.SetCenter(latLng);
    }
```

how come i can't set the map to center of the coordinate?
Firebug with this error

```
TypeError: map123.setCenter is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

map123.setCenter(latLng);
```

### EDITED

where is my GMapPanel.js download from https://raw.github.com/VinylFox/ExtJS.ux.GMapPanel/master/src/GMapPanel3.js
then i put it in my localhost/ux/GMapPanel3.js
and this is my config before use the GMapPanel

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'ux/');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.window.MessageBox',
    'Ext.window.*',
    'Ext.ux.GMapPanel'
]);
```

but fail to set Center , why?

Comment: What is the class definition of `mygooglemap`?  The class definition of that object doesn't have the `setCenter` function defined.

Comment: @kevhender i have edited the class of `mygooglemap` ... have a look please

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the plugin from here: https://github.com/VinylFox/ExtJS.ux.GMapPanel

Assuming that is true, from looking at the code it looks like you need to use `getMap()` on your `gmappanel` before calling `setCenter()`:

```
map123.getMap().setCenter(latLng);
```

Or, you can specify the `setCenter` property when configuring the `gmappanel`:

```
{
    xtype: 'gmappanel',
    region: 'center',
    id : 'mygooglemap',
    setCenter: {
        lat: 3.951941, 
        long: 102.052002
    },
    mapOptions: {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP                    
    }
}
```

One of the great things about ExtJS/Javascript is that you have access to the code of all of your libraries.  When you see errors like "xxx is not a function", it should be pretty self-explanatory: the function you are trying to use is not available on the object on which you are calling it.

Comment: TypeError: map123.getMap is not a function. map123.getMap().setCenter(latLng); , this is what i get from getMap ERROR

Comment: i think is my GMapPanel loaded fail? i have edited the source above, please have a look

Comment: What happens when you view `map123` on the console?  `console.log(map123)`